# c# xml serialization showing reversed object graph

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I am new to C# and would like to serialize an object graph to a XML.
I am almost done, but for unknown reasons the XML is showing me the object graph reversed.

```
public class PersonalDetails
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public AddressDetails address;
    public PersonalDetails()
    {

    }
    public PersonalDetails(string Name, int Age, AddressDetails address)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Age = Age;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public class AddressDetails
    {
        [XmlElement("Number")]
        public int HouseNo;
        [XmlElement("Street")]
        public string StreetName;
        public string City;
        public AddressDetails()
        {

        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            AddressDetails address = new AddressDetails();
            PersonalDetails[] personal = new PersonalDetails[1];
            personal[0] = new PersonalDetails("Roberto", 15, address);

            address.HouseNo = 4;
            address.StreetName = "ABC";
            address.City = "Delhi";

            Serialize(personal[0]);
        }
        public static void Serialize(PersonalDetails personal)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PersonalDetails));
            using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("TestXML.xml"))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, personal);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is how me current XML is looking:

```
<PersonalDetails xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <address>
    <Number>4</Number>
    <Street>ABC</Street>
    <City>Delhi</City>
  </address>
  <Name>Roberto</Name>
  <Age>15</Age>
</PersonalDetails>
```

But i want this:

```
<PersonalDetails xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Name>Roberto</Name>
  <Age>15</Age>
  <address>
    <Number>4</Number>
    <Street>ABC</Street>
    <City>Delhi</City>
  </address>
</PersonalDetails>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element order, generally, does not really matter in serialization, however that being said you can use the `XmlElement` attribute (you are already using it for specifying the name). If you really want it to be ordered a specific way you can use the `Order` property of the `XmlElement` attribute on your fields:

```
public class PersonalDetails
{

    [XmlElement(Order = 1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(Order = 2)]
    public int Age { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(Order = 3)]
    public AddressDetails address;
    public PersonalDetails()
    {

    }
    public PersonalDetails(string Name, int Age, AddressDetails address)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Age = Age;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public class AddressDetails
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Number", Order = 1)]
        public int HouseNo;
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Street", Order = 2)]
        public string StreetName;
        [XmlElement(Order = 3)]
        public string City;
        public AddressDetails()
        {

        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            AddressDetails address = new AddressDetails();
            PersonalDetails[] personal = new PersonalDetails[1];
            personal[0] = new PersonalDetails("Roberto", 15, address);

            address.HouseNo = 4;
            address.StreetName = "ABC";
            address.City = "Delhi";

            Serialize(personal[0]);
        }
        public static void Serialize(PersonalDetails personal)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PersonalDetails));
            using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("TestXML.xml"))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, personal);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing public fields and public properties. XmlSerializer gives priority to fields. That's why you experience an order of elements that may seem counter-intuitive.

Stick with public properties *only* and the order will be as you'd expect. There's no need to specify explicit order.